# How can I find the logging level of the root in log4net?

Tags: log4net

Given a Log4Net logger on my C# ASP.NET application, how can I get the logging level of the root logger?

The specific error case I am trying to trap is that when the root is set to `trace` it causes an error in NHibernate because of the version we are on, so I would just like to trap that and shut down the WCF service in the case where someone sets the log level incorrectly.

I'm sure someone else has tried to do this before, so I would like to benefit from prior knowledge. My google fu is weak tonight. Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rootLogger = ((Hierarchy) LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
if (rootLogger.Level == Level.Trace) …
```

Comment: If you don't mind terribly, I'll hit the accept button once I've had a chance to test this, but I think you hit it exactly. Thank you.